Does $x'' + x + \arctan x = \lambda \sin t$ have a $2\pi$ periodic solution when $\lambda <2$？
It's easy to show that the equation $x'' + x + \arctan x = \lambda \sin t$ doesn't have a $2\pi$ periodic solution when $\lambda \geq 2$:
Suppose $\lambda \geq 2$ and $\varphi(t)$ is a $2\pi$ periodic solution then
$$
\begin{align}
\lambda \pi &= \lambda \int _{0}^{2\pi} \sin ^{2}t \, dt\\
&= \int _{0}^{2\pi} \varphi'' (t) \sin t + \varphi (t) \sin t + \arctan \varphi(t) \sin t \, dt\\
& = \int _{0}^{2\pi} \arctan \varphi(t) \sin t \, dt\\
& < \frac{\pi}{2} \int _{0}^{2\pi} |\sin t | \, dt\\
& = 2\pi
\end{align}
$$
And this is a contradiction since $\lambda \geq 2$.
What can we say about the $2\pi$ periodic solution when $\lambda <2$? I tried to solve this equation using mathematica and when $\lambda \geq 2$ there is no numerical solution while when $\lambda <2$ there is one, so I think that there should be one $2\pi$ periodic solution when $\lambda <2$，but I don't know how to prove it.

There is a result of Seifert on periodic solutions of $x''+g(x)=p(t)$ where $p$ is periodic, $g$ is continuous and increasing, $g(0)=0$ and $|g(x)| > \max |p|$ for $|x|$ sufficiently large. Maybe it is of some help, see here: https://community.ams.org/journals/proc/1959-010-03/S0002-9939-1959-0107057-2/S0002-9939-1959-0107057-2.pdf
